# Mdiparent ,child forms

Tags: vb.net, mdiparent

I have mdiparent and many child forms
im calling a child form as below

```
     Private Sub tsmQuotation_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsmQuotation.Click
            If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Quotation).Any Then
                 Quotation.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
                 Quotation.Focus()
            Else
                 Quotation.MdiParent = Me
                 Quotation.Show()
            End If
     End Sub
```

my first doubt is: when i declare this  Quotation.MdiParent = Me...it takes more time to open the form than without this line. How can i reduce the time to open form..or am I doing anything wrong ?

2nd doubt is: I have place a picturebox in mdiparent's center. and i have sent picturebox to back but then too when i open any child form I see the picturebox above the quotaion .I want to show picture box at back not above any child forms.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `Quotation.MdiParent = Me`, the form displayed would not be an MdiChild.  It would instead be displaying as a normal form by itself.  Try dragging it around the screen and you'll see that it is not confined to the MdiParent form.

See if this loads it any faster, though:

```
Private Sub tsmQuotation_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tsmQuotation.Click
    If Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Quotation).Any Then
        Dim Q As Quotation = Application.OpenForms().OfType(Of Quotation).First
        Q.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal
        Q.Activate()
    Else
        Dim Q As New Quotation
        Q.MdiParent = Me
        Q.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

For the second issue, select the MdiParent form and set the BackgroundImage() and BackgroundImageLayout() properties.  The image will NOT display on the form at design-time, but it will be there when you run the application.

Comment: Thanks your reply solved 2nd issue but the first issue is still there ..it still takes time.

Comment: Idle _Mind can u have look at my other question because no one replying on it..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15619179/crystal-report-layout-designer-in-vb-net-form ..if not crystal report is there anyother tool through which I can allow user to change the layout of controls in reports..Im even ready to pay for it..because its too urgent for me.

Comment: Does the slow loading form load any data from a database?...or have any significant code in Load() or Shown()?

Comment: no it doesnt load any data. It makes the form appear as patches and then form....this takes more time when i run the app for first time after starting the pc